# Generate a link from Google Maps center to another mapping site

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, forms

Using the `Google Maps API v3`, I'd like to take the map center coordinates and construct a `URL` based on them that would send a user to an external mapping site.

Constructing the `URL` is not the problem, however keeping the `URLs` updated as the map moves is. I'm wondering if it would be possible to have an `onClick` event on my submit button that would grab the current `lat`, `lng`, `zoom`, and the site the user wants to go to (selected from a dropdown menu.).

I was planning on pushing those variables out to a `.php` page that would take the variables, construct the `URL`, and then redirect the user.

The `PHP` part and the `HTML` form part is trivial - getting the variables over to the php script is what is stumping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript-part isn't less trivial, observe the `idle` -event of the map and set values of input's (these may be hidden) with the values:
script:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(mapObject, 'idle',function(){
        document.someForm.lat.value=this.getCenter().lat();
        document.someForm.lng.value=this.getCenter().lng();
        document.someForm.zoom.value=this.getZoom();
         });
```

form:

```
<form name="someForm">
  <input name="lat" /><input name="lng"/><input name="zoom"/>
</form>
```

However, when all that you need from the PHP-script is to build the URL, this also can be easily done via javascript.

Comment: See my comment below for why constructing the URL in Javascript hasn't worked for me. Thinking about it, though, I think your method should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you bother pushing the lat, lng and zoom over to a PHP page? Construct the URL locally in javascript.

The Map object has getZoom and getCenter functions.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

Comment: Well, the problem that I have had with trying that (because I have another thing in my map that sends people to a new page) is that I have seen that changing window.location() doesn't seem to work reliably. I'm developing using Safari, and the only way that I can make Safari go to another page is by pushing out to something like a php page that sets the header location.

Comment: In the end I ended up getting it to work in Javascript after all.